# ImageMagick: Annotating a picture

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am just getting started with ImageMagick, and I don't quite have the hang of it yet. For the moment I am working with the command line, trying to draw some text on an image. Here is the comand line I am using:

```
convert "D:\Users\dcveeneman\Desktop\Pictures\Baden-Powell\Baden-Powell 001.JPG" -font Arial -pointsize 24 -fill #FFFF0000 -weight Bold -annotate 0 "2011-07-26 8:57:06" "D:\Users\dcveeneman\Desktop\temp\Baden-Powell 001.JPG"
```

I am not getting an error message, but I am not getting any text on the output picture either. Both the source and destination paths have been verified. I am hoping soeone can point out the error in my command line. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you've chosen generating the command-line arguments rather than using a library such as [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I am doing this as a learning exercise in creating Windows shells for console apps. ImageMagick.NET would certainly be easier. I have simplified the question to get it down to the command line.

Comment: **Obligatory:** *Waiting for the inevitable lol-cats generator side-project to be made*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. My most fundamental problem appears to have been with the `-fill` parameter. My command line arguments are being generated by a C# program, which iterates a folder of pictures, time stamping each one. In any event, C# was providing an ARGB hex value for the color, instead of an RGBA value, or one of the color names, that ImageMagick recognizes.

I also added an offset to the -annotate argument (+100+100, to offset from the upper left. Here is the working command line:

```
convert "D:\Users\dcveeneman\Desktop\Pictures\Baden-Powell\Baden-Powell 001.JPG" -font Arial -pointsize 24 -fill Red -weight Bold -annotate +100+100 "2011-07-26 8:57:06" "D:\Users\dcveeneman\Desktop\temp\Baden-Powell 001.JPG"
```

I hope that helps someone else down the road!